# Custom list class __getitem__ method fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have my custom list class called `Stack` like so:

```
class Stack():
  def __init__(self):
    self.items = []

  def append(self, item):
    self.items.append(item)
  
  def __getitem__(self, slc):
    if isinstance(slc, int):
      return self.items[slc]
    else:
      return self.__class__(self.items[slc])
```

Notice the `__getitem__` method which I use for slicing functionality.  It casts a type on a sliced list.  This is also the same what the `collections.UserList` or `collections.abc.Sequence` are doing.

Now I want to inherit `Stack` and populate `stack.items` with some data. `some_data` is a regular python list which contains `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],...]`, I do it like so:

```
class SpecificStack(Stack):
  def __init__(self, some_data):
    super().__init__()
    
    for d in some_data:
       item = {'time': d[0], 'place': d[1], 'order': d[2]}
       self.append( item )
```

If I now try to slice `SpecificStack` object instance:

```
ss = SpecificStack(some_data)
ss[:5]
```

The `__getitem__` slicing functionality goes wrong.  I get `KeyError` in `__getitem__` `return self.__class__(self.items[slc])`. What is happening here?

Comment: Quick check - you have a typo in `__getimtem__`, it's intended?

Comment: just a typo. Thanks :)

Comment: The problem is what he/she said in the answer but your goal is a bit unclear for me, please tell what do you expect when `slc` is int or is slice object? I suggest to print `ss.items` before `ss[:5]` to see what is in there and then track the `__getitem__` method to see the problem yourself.

Comment: If `slc` is `int` I want to return a single element from `Stack.items[5]` of whatever type the element is, on the other hand if `slc` is a `slice` I want `Stack.items[:5]` to be of the `SpecificStack` type.  Later on my `SpecificStack` will have methods which I will want to perform on a slice of `SpecificStack`.  Could you please clarify `ss.name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither your `Stack.__init__` nor your `SpecificStack.__init__` take the arguments `__getitem__` is passing.

`Stack.__init__` doesn't take any arguments but `self`, and `SpecificStack.__init__` wants an iterable of sequences, but `__getitem__` is passing it an iterable of dicts.

Comment: I am not following, sorry, the terminology is still quite new for me.  Could you please tell me where to edit my code, I may easier catch the idea.

Comment: I am still hanging on this one.  As far as I understand I have to `super().__init__(items)` in `SpecificStack` class, where items is an empty list?